# Entity Framework Add user to db error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to learn MVC3. I am just at the moment trying to add a user to a db.

```
db.U1_Users.Add(u1_Users);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The error occurs when it gets to the save.
I this it is an issue with the add function.

I get the error

```
InnerException = {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'U1_UserID', table
'Admin.dbo.U1_User'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

EDIT

U1_UserID is the primary key.

This is the model:

```
public class U1_User
    {

      public int U1_UserID { get; set; }
      public string U1_UserName {get;set;}

    }
```

Comment: This happens because your model definition has an issue, please post you model class source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed..

```
[Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty straight forward to me. You need to make sure the value is set. If you want this to be an Auto Number then you need to set that on your DB.

In SQL SERVER you can open the table in design mode, go to table properties and select the column as the Identity Column. Also, you should make the field a primary key.

Comment: If you doing Entity Framework Code First, this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This happens cause you gave your id propertie the wrong name.

The naming convention is :

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
```

or

```
        public int YourModelNameId { get; set; }
```

If you want to map to an existing Database have a look at the modelBuilder in ScottGu´s Blog Post:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx

The following will work:

```
    public class U1_Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int U1_UsersID { get; set; }
        public string U1_UserName { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: U1_UserID is the field name in the DB

Comment: Check out ScottGu´s Blog. Thats all you need. I have a link in my answer

Comment: I changed the names still the same